# General wordpress link filter

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

everyone! I need to add the domain prefix www, not to write by hand, each filter as post_link, page_link, category_link and so on - there is a global filter to all urls added www. Methods of how to change the general settings in the site url in the database or change options or htaccess - just do not fit. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can't change it via the wp-admin, you can use the following:

```
        add_filter( 'post_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 10, 3);
        add_filter( 'page_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 10, 3);
        add_filter( 'post_type_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 10, 3);
        add_filter( 'category_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 11, 3);
        add_filter( 'tag_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 10, 3);
        add_filter( 'author_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 11, 3);
        add_filter( 'day_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 11, 3);
        add_filter( 'month_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 11, 3);
        add_filter( 'year_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 11, 3);

        function changePermalinks($permalink, $post) {

                if ( strpos($permalink, '://www.') ) return $permalink;

                return str_replace('://', '://www.', $permalink);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your dashboard go to Settings -> General and the fourth and fifth option should be "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)". Change the `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com` and it should change all links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution is not for me.

Comment: Okay, can you explain why that isn't the solution?

Comment: Because on our hosting this options is remove from admin panel.

Comment: in 2016 this in functions.php results in a blank url

`add_filter( 'post_link', array($this, 'changePermalinks'), 10, 3);function changePermalinks($permalink, $post) {
  $search               = array('#devauthor#is','#author#is');
  $replace              = array('www','www');
  $thePermalink         = preg_replace($search, $replace, $permalink);
  return $thePermalink;
}`

Comment: ^ if not in object context then shouldn't use `$this` keyword. So it'll be `add_filter( 'post_link' , 'changePermalinks')` as opposed to `add_filter( 'post_link' , array($this, 'changePermalinks'))`